# Cannot setup Samba

Tags: networking, windows, raspberry-pi, samba, services

I want to access files from my Raspberry on my Windows machine. I did it previously, but I resetted both my devices some time ago. I haven't made any advanced network configurations to them yet. I installed Samba on the Raspberry with `apt install samba`. Then appended to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[shared]
path = /home/pi/shared
valid users = pi
read only = no
```

(I tried in other instances by adding or removing additional properties to the config, such as `browsable`, but the same result). Then made a Samba user with `smbpasswd -a pi`. I tried both using password and no in different instances. I used `ufw allow samba`, again, one time yes and one time no (before I didn't needed it). While installing Samba I chose both paths of that DHCP config, but the same result. Finally, `service smbd restart`. U can imagine I did all of those as root user already. The Pi doesn't show on `Network` folder, but it didn't appear before either. The way I was going was with `Add a network location`. The folder `shared` is made on Pi and made it `777` just to make sure it is not the problem, the same as on `/home/pi`. After trying to add `\\192.168.0.100\shared` or `\\192.168.0.100\pi`, the Windows tells me it can't find the location and I don't get prompted for credentials.

Below is my network configuration:

```
192.168.0.1: router
192.168.0.100: Pi
192.168.0.102: Windows
```

I'm connected to the Pi using ssh, so I'm sure the ip is right. Basically what I did before was bruteforce all known possible configurations, and none showed a good result. I checked the workgroup too and they are the same. I did multiple combinations in restarting the devices (inclusive the router). On Windows I also made combinations of `discoverable` and `file sharing` options too

What I did wrong?

(I moved to this forum from `https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/` as I was told I have higher chances to get the answer there)

Edit: config with no-comment lines:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
[shared]
path = /home/pi/shared
valid users = pi
read only = no
```

Comment: Can you at least ping the Raspberry Pi from the Windows 10 computer?

Comment: As I said on the post, I'm connected to it via ssh @NasirRiley

Comment: You didn't say that you were connected to it from your Windows 10 computer. Have you tried disabling the firewall altogether?

Comment: I have ssh into it from the Windows 10 device. The firewall from what device u mean to disable @NasirRiley?

Comment: From the Raspberri Pi.

Comment: You have a Unix user called 'pi' You have created a Samba user called 'pi' But do you have a Windows user called 'pi'?

Comment: @NasirRiley, the Raspberry does not come by default with any firewall at all, and the iptables are set to allow everything by kernel. Since the device is fresh I haven't made any firewall configuration. On top of that the `ufw` command shall be fixing the problem "just in case". I must mention I made tests with both using `ufw` and not. The ones without `ufw` were made before its installation

Comment: @roaima, the Windows client doesn't prompt me. I edited the post for the `smb.conf`